# Is there a way to exclude annotation from Javadoc

Tags: java, annotations, javadoc

I do not want to include the Java annotations in the Javadoc. Is there any way to achieve that?

Comment: Please add a comment before downvoting

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get what you want. What do you have, javadoc file or source code? 
If it's the javadoc file, all of them are considered annotations in java and you can't exclude the whole thing.

If it's the source code, all javadoc annotations inside the file goes after a "@". You can either search it and remove it manually or use a small program to delete it:
    read in a line;
    delete everything after "@" sign in this line;
Or you can just remove all the annotations.

Hope it helps and hope you could maybe make your question a bit more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You might use comments surely, but I'm currently facing the same issue, which is basically issue with annotations in a library project. To be able to deploy it to bintray, I've had to add following to library project:

```
    configurations {
        javadocDeps
    }
    dependencies {
// otherwise can't build javaDocs
        javadocDeps "com.android.support:support-annotations:$supportLibraryVersion"
    }
```

Now I'm not able to use this library, because I keep getting error in main project:

> Error:Failed to resolve: annotationProcessor

So using {@code Intdef} instead of {@link Intdef} in library jdocs might help, haven't tried it yet, but I'd rather use those annotations in javadocs as well. Apparently for now need to remove those from jdoc's.